# Why does the compiler have to know the type of one lambda?

Tags: c#, lambda, action

this code is not easy to read, sorry for that, but for my interest, why does the compiler have to know the type of the lambda. Let's see the code, no worries, it's not real code.

```
bool b1 = true, b2, b3;
Action action = () => Console.WriteLine("Hello");
(b1 ? () => 
  {
    b2 = true;
    b3 = false;
  } : action)();
```

That works. But...

Why can't I do this?

```
bool b1 = true, b2, b3;
(b1 ? () => 
  {
    b2 = true;
    b3 = false;
  } : () => Console.WriteLine("Hello"))();
```

Can you please explain, in which cases the compiler have to know the explicit type of the function (in this case `Action`)?

VS2017 told me that....

> CS0173 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because
>   there is no implicit conversion between 'lambda expression' and
>   'lambda expression'

Comment: What you get as result? If it's a compiler error you should mention it

Comment: Am I wrong or could `()=>{} ` also be a `Func<>` ? (what could be the reason, I think)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there is no delegate equivalence in .NET: you can have two delegates that have the same signature, like

```
delegate void MyDelegate1()
```

and

```
delegate void MyDelegate2()
```

but you can't assign one delegate to the other... You can't:

```
MyDelegate1 del1 = null;
MyDelegate2 del2 = del1;
```

They are distinct and incompatible delegate types. They are "similar" only from the "human" standpoint, not from the standpoint of the compiler/of .NET .

Clearly if the exact "type" of delegate (and not only its signature) is important in .NET, then .NET can't "desume" it. In your first example the compiler can see that the delegate type is `Action`, so it can infer that `() => { ... }` is an `Action`. In the second example the compiler doesn't have this "hint".